# Why "erholsamen" and not "erholsames"?

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective, declension

Why "erholsamen" and not "erholsames" given that "Wochenende" is neuter?

Which is correct?

> Nach einem erholsamen Wochenende begann er seine Arbeit am Montag mit neuem Schwung.

or

> Nach einem erholsames Wochenende begann er seine Arbeit am Montag mit neuem Schwung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a dative and any [table of adjectival declensions](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/adjectives/declension) will tell you that after an indefinite article, the ending for adjectives when the noun is neuter and in dative is -en; the example given in that table is *einem netten Kind*.

Comment: The question can be closed if it can be answered by a declension table.

Comment: The purpose of this website would perhaps be served best if the question could be closed without even mentioning a declension table so that independent research by the question opener is encouraged. *That* will tell him, no?

Comment: @bakunin not sure if sarcasm or not, but I'm astounded that there are two answers and 7 upvotes on a by definition off-topic question.

Comment: @infinitezero: perhaps this discussion should be held in Meta and not here, but in short: I for my part am here because I want to help others struggling with German. I am not here for the who-can-close-more-threads competition. Most questions here could be answered by reading the right book or article, so perhaps each and every question should be closed with "you can research that yourself with a non-infinite effort". Everybody could get a Master degree in Germanistics, Linguistics, and Philology and then know what he wanted to ask here.

Comment: @bakunin we already had that discussion: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/beantworten-von-off-topic-fragen but in my opinion StackExchange is the wrong format for your quest. This side is way more lenient though than for example stackoverflow, and I think it's difference in quality is quite obvious.

Comment: I have answered there. Now, if you want me to leave, I am ready to delete my account.....

Answer (score 3):

The word *»erholsam«* is an adjective, and the declension of adjectives is rather complicated. There are 5 (five) different grammatical features, that determine how an adjective is declined.

Before explaining these features, there is an additional rule: Adjectives are only declined, if they are used as an attribute of another word (usually of a noun):

- **Attributive usage** (adjective must be declined)

  > Das **rote** Auto gehört mir.

  "Red" is a property of the car and the word "red" is bound directly to the word "car".
- **Predicative usage** (adjective is bound to the noun by a copula verb; adjective must not be declined)

  > Das Auto ist **rot.**

  "Red" is a again property of the car, but now the binding between "red" and "car" is made by the copula verb "ist".
- **Adverbial usage** (adjective is attribute of a verb, not of a noun; adjective must not be declined)

  > Das Auto fährt **schnell.**

  "Fast" is not a property of the car, but of it's movement which is expressed by the verb "fährt" (a form of "fahren"). So the adjective is not a property of the noun but a property of the verb.

---

Now, that we know, that adjectives are only declined when they are used attributive, we can have a look on how this declension is influenced by grammatical features of its environment:

#### Gender of the noun

masculine, feminine, neuter

In German all nouns have a grammatical gender that is a property of the noun and that can be masculine (der Löffel, der Mann), feminine (die Gabel, die Frau) or neuter (das Messer, das Kind). And this gender influences the declension of an attributive adjective:

- Ein **neuer** Löffel glänzt. Ein **dicker** Mann schläft.
- Eine **neue** Gabel glänzt. Eine **dicke** Frau schläft.
- Ein **neues** Messer glänzt. Ein **dickes** Kind schläft.

#### Grammatical number

singular, plural

- Ein **neuer** Löffel glänzt. Ein **dicker** Mann schläft.
- Viele **neue** Löffel glänzen. Viele **dicke** Männer schlafen.

#### Grammatical case

nominative, genitive, dative, accusative

- Ein **neuer** Löffel glänzt. Ein **dicker** Mann schläft.
- Georg bedient sich eines **neuen** Löffels. Irene entsinnt sich eines **dicken** Mannes.
- Georg nähert sich einem **neuen** Löffel. Irene dankt einem **dicken** Mann.
- Georg sieht einen **neuen** Löffel. Irene begrüßt einen **dicken** Mann.

#### comparison

positive, comparative, superlative

- Der **neue** Löffel glänzt. Der **dicke** Mann schläft.
- Der **neuere** Löffel glänzt. Der **dickere** Mann schläft.
- Der **neueste** Löffel glänzt. Der **dickste** Mann schläft.

#### Definiteness

strong, weak, mixed

A determiner is a word like an article (die Frau, eine Frau) or a pronoun (meine Frau, jede Frau) that defines if we are talking about this specific woman (then its defined) or about any woman (then its undefined). But sometimes a determiner can also be missing, and these three possibilities of determinedness (defined, undefined, missing) lead to three different kinds of adjectivic declension:

- **strong declension** when there is no determiner:

  > **Guter** Wein ist teuer.
- **weak declension** when the definiteness is defined:

  > Der **gute** Wein ist teuer.
- **mixed declension** when the definiteness is undefined:

  > Ein **guter** Wein ist teuer.

---

This was your sentence:

> Nach einem **erholsamen** Wochenende begann er seine Arbeit am Montag mit neuem Schwung.

The adjective *»erholsamen«* (a form of *»erholsam«*) is an attribute of the noun *»Wochenende«* in the nominal phrase *»einem erholsamen Wochenende«.* This defines attributive usage, and therefor the adjective must be declined.

- Gender: neuter
  The noun *»Wochenende«* is a compound noun, built from the feminine noun *die Woche* and the neuter noun *das Ende.* The compound noun always inherits the gender of it's last component, so the whole word *»Wochenende«* is neuter, and therefore also the adjective must be declined neuter.
- Number: singular
  We are talking about only one weekend, so it's singular.
- Case: dative
  The nominal group *»einem erholsamen Wochenende«* is part of the adverbial modifier (adverbiale Bestimmung) *»nach einem erholsamen Wochenende«* that begins with the preposition *»nach«* which forces the rest of the adverbial to be in dative case, and so also the adjective must be used in dative case.
- comparison: positive
  The weekend was not more restful (comparative) or most restful (superlative) but just restful (positive)
- definiteness: mixed
  The determiner of the nominal group *»einem erholsamen Wochenende«* is the indefinite article *»einem«* (a form of *»ein«*), and this indefinite determiner is the cause for the adjective to be declined mixed.

Now you have all you need to look up this word in a declension table like this: [declension of "erholsam"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:erholsam)

This table is overall grouped by comparison in three sections (Positiv, Komparativ, Superlativ). We chose the first section: **Positiv**

Next we need to identify the correct block by definiteness. Our block is the last: **Gemischte Deklination** (mixed declension)

The number (**Singular**) and the Gender (**Neutrum**) tell us which column we need, and at the end we select the right entry by the grammatical case, which is **Dativ**, and then we get:

> **erholsamen**